# Is there any way to identify requests coming to custom origin server from CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront with custom origin and want to redirect certain requests coming to a web app to CloudFront (clients use direct URLs, which cannot be changed to CloudFront-based URLs). In order to ensure that cache on CloudFront is updated properly, I must not redirect requests coming from CloudFront itself. Is there any way to identify such requests on origin server?

Does CloudFront add any custom headers to requests sent to origin server? Or is there any other reliable way to determine that requests is coming from CloudFront?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes you can identify requests coming to your origin server from cloudfront by checking the useragent. the user agent would be 'Amazon CloudFront'

Comment: Also see answer below for a MAJOR pitfall: "CloudFront sends an empty User-Agent to the origin"

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

It's an old question, but my update useful for someone research or looking for the new solution.

Recently AWS added new feature Origin Custom Headers.You can set a header with a secret value and check it on your origin server by the web server or your applications.

[image]

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Otherwise, you cannot prevent that another CloudFront customer sets up a distribution and points it at your origin. A simple check for the CloudFront IP, UserAgent or any other common attribute is not sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

### Update

Avinash Bijja correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751637/45773) (+1) that the HTTP [User-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header *would be 'Amazon CloudFront'* for requests coming from Amazon CloudFront servers. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be explicitly documented indeed, but is implicitly acknowledged by various posts in the respective forum, see e.g. the AWS Team response to [User Agent String - does CF overwrite the user agent string?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=420294#420294):

> You are correct. The User-Agent field is always populated as "Amazon CloudFront".

<strike>However, it turns out this is not currently entirely reliable, insofar [CloudFront sends an empty User-Agent to the origin](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=370577#370577) if one is missing in the originating client request already:</strike>

> I can confirm that CloudFront is not sending a User-Agent to the
>   origin when the original client does not send a User-Agent. We have
>   enhancements & fixes to User-Agent handling on our backlog, but no
>   release dates at this time. I've sent you a PM with further details.

These enhancements & fixes are apparently not rolled out still as of February 07 2013 at least.

These enhancements & fixes [have been rolled out as of August 05 2013](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=370577#475819) (thanks [webbiedave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524973/is-there-any-way-to-identify-requests-coming-to-custom-origin-server-from-cloudf/13550795?noredirect=1#comment27667418_13550795) for the update!).

---

### Initial Answer

> Does CloudFront add any custom headers to requests sent to origin
>   server?

One would think so indeed, but at least they don't appear to be documented where I would have expected it, namely in [How CloudFront Processes and Forwards Requests to Your Custom Origin Server](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestBehaviorCustomOrigin). Given you are in control of the origin server, you might just check its HTTP access logs though?

> Or is there any other reliable way to determine that requests is
>   coming from CloudFront?

You'll need to judge the reliability yourself, but *The IP address that CloudFront forwards to the origin server is the IP addresses of a CloudFront server, not the IP address of the end user's computer.* - consequently you could restrict access to the published [Amazon CloudFront Public IP Ranges](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=910); however, be aware of the respective disclaimer:

> The CloudFront IP addresses change frequently and we cannot guarantee
>   advance notice of changes. On a best-effort basis, we will provide the
>   list of current addresses. **Customers should not use these addresses
>   for mission critical applications** and must never hard code them in DNS
>   names. *[emphasis mine]*

Consequently you'll need to monitor this forum/post to take notice of respective changes as early as possible (if this constraint is acceptable for your use case in the first place of course).

Comment: I can confirm that as of today this is still an issue.  CloudFront will not send a user-agent if the original request has an empty user-agent.

Comment: This has apparently been fixed as of August 5 2013. [The fix to always send the user-agent string "Amazon CloudFront" with the origin request has been deployed.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=370577#475819)

Comment: @webbiedave - thanks much, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront appears to add a `X-Amz-Cf-Id` header to every request before forwarding it to the origin.  At least, it currently is doing that for me.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment on Reza's answer, but I can't do that :).

For completeness, here's the link to the official documentation regarding [Forwarding Custom Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html), which currently claims the following.

> You can configure CloudFront to include custom headers whenever it forwards a request to your origin. You can specify the names and values of custom headers for each origin, both for custom origins and for Amazon S3 buckets. Custom headers have a variety of uses, such as the following:
>
> > You can identify the requests that are forwarded to your custom origin by CloudFront. This is useful if you want to know whether users are bypassing CloudFront or if you're using more than one CDN and you want information about which requests are coming from each CDN. (If you're using an Amazon S3 origin and you enable Amazon S3 server access logging, the logs don't include header information.)